# Are there other expressions than "sans bourse délier" that share this odd word order?

Tags: expressions, ordre-des-mots

I said jokingly in conversation:

> Tu me demandes des renseignements ? Et **sans bourse délier**, en plus ? Pourvu que je puisse au moins m'en jeter un à l’œil !

Looking back, I have always used this phrasing without thinking much about its *odd* construction, or more specifically, the placement of "bourse". I'd sooner expect the phrase to take the form of "***sans délier ta bourse***" or "***sans la délier***".

I wonder how this word order is considered grammatical? I recall seeing native speakers use this expression several times, and it was "sans bourse délier" each time.

Le Petit Robert, Wiktionnaire et j'en passe, à l'appui.

Comment: *Comments removed*. Please only use comments to ask for clarification or suggest improvements to the post. Providing insights can at times be acceptable, but discussions are not to be hosted in comments. If you'd like to discuss please move the conversation(s) to the [chat].

Answer (score 4):

This word order unsual but it can  be found in poetry or fixed expressions. [*Sans coup férir*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sans_coup_f%C3%A9rir) is another similar expression which you may hear once in a while. I suppose there are more on the same model.

Comment: *Sans mot dire*

Answer (score 3):

To add another example to Stéphane's reply: “[Il faut raison garder](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/il_faut_savoir_raison_garder)”.

Answer (score 3):

There could be *“il y a”*, commonly following *“puisque qqch”*, among other uses:

- Les raquettes sont embarassantes, mais prenons-les donc aujourd’hui, puisque neige **il y a** et qu’on en annonce encore dans la journée.
- Quand tout va bien, ça ne prend que dix minutes, mais puisque problème **il y a**, on peut s’attendre à y passer une heure.

And without *“puisque”*:

- Lorsqu’il y a des odeurs, et odeurs **il y a** souvent, envoyez un peu d’eau dans le tuyau. Un plombier viendra dans quelques jours.

---

*“Chemin faisant”* is another common expression featuring the absence of the article as well as an inversion of usual word order:

> **Chemin faisant,** il vit le col du chien pelé.
>   Qu'est-ce là ? lui dit-il. —Rien. —Quoi, rien ? —Peu de chose.
>   —Mais encor ? —Le collier dont je suis attaché
>   De ce que vous voyez est peut-être la cause.
>   —Attaché ! dit le loup : vous ne courez donc pas
>   Où vous voulez ?
>       –*Le loup et le chien,* Jean de La Fontaine

*“À tout venant”* pretty much follows the same pattern as *“chemin faisant”*, but it also saw its usage extended in the creation of a noun: *“le tout-venant”*, also spelled without the hyphen, *“le tout venant”* ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tout-venant)). Initially, in the XIX<sup>th</sup> century, a specialized word used in the mining industry to designate unsorted ore coming up from the mine, it was eventually incorporated in the commercial language, before working its way in the general vocabulary of most of the population.

> « Que faisiez-vous au temps chaud ? »
>   Dit-elle à cette emprunteuse.
>   « Nuit et jour **à tout venant**
>   Je chantais, ne vous déplaise.
>       –*La cigale et la fourmi,* Jean de La Fontaine
>
> J'en suis arrivé, à présent, après tant de mésaventures, à me demander si ce qu'on appelle incroyable, invraisemblable, n'est pas en définitive **le tout-venant** que les habitudes et les préjugés nous empêchent de regarder comme des choses normales.
>       –*Chroniques de mauvaise compagnie*, Alphonse Boudard

---

A recent [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/28402/a-few-questions-about-the-french-version-of-the-canadian-national-anthem) about the French version of the Canadian National Anthem showed that such an inversion is used in it. Though it is by no mean a common phrase, its location in such an official piece of poetry gives it a fairly high visibility, though mostly by Canadians, and some value as an example here, I believe:

> Et ta valeur, **de foi trempée,**
>   Protégera nos foyers et nos droits.

Answer (score 2):

Dans un article traitant de certaines réflexions au sujet des locutions verbales, on présente une brève classification des expressions figées selon deux axes, incluant un exemple mentionné en [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/28339/are-there-other-expressions-than-sans-bourse-d%C3%A9lier-that-share-this-odd-word-o#comment57485_28340) :

> 1. Les EF syntaxiquement bien formées, mais de sens global, non
>      compositionnel. Elles peuvent avoir en outre une lecture
>      compositionnelle, littérale (*le talon d’Achille, ramasser une
>      veste, avaler des couleuvres*).
> 2. Les EF syntaxiquement déviantes, et de sens global, non
>      compositionnel (*avoir beau + infinitif, de guerre lasse, à bout
>      portant, faire état, à cœur joie*).
> 3. Les EF syntaxiquement déviantes, mais de sens compositionnel (***sans
>      mot dire***, chemin faisant, avoir faim, prendre la fuite).
> 4. Les EF syntaxiquement bien formées et de sens compositionnel (*à
>      l’exception de, à la place de, prendre une décision*).
>
> [ David Gaatone, [*Les marqueurs d’intensité et les locutions verbales :
>   quelques réflexions*](https://www.cairn.info/revue-travaux-de-linguistique-2007-2-page-93.htm) ds. Travaux de linguistique 2007/2 (n° 55), ed.
>   de Boeck Supérieur, je souligne. ]

Si l'on prend pour acquis que *sans mot dire* est du même type que *sans bourse délier* et [*sans coup férir*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/28340) présenté ailleurs, on a ainsi quelques exemples pour réfléchir aux concepts de « déviance syntaxique » et au principe de [*compositionnalité*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8396876) avec les expressions généralement regroupées sous la catégorie « verbe + substantif », indépendamment de tout procédé d'[inversion](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4086) le cas échéant. La déviance n'emporte pas nécessairement l'incohérence et n'ayant jamais entendu l'expression en question je la considère d'une facture impeccable et parfaitement intelligible.

Comment: Est-ce que ce pourrait être un reste des propositions infinitives qu'on rencontre en latin ? Je pose cette question car je crois me rappeler que dans ce genre de construction, l'infinitif est le plus souvent à la fin.

Comment: Ça me fait penser à ces particules négatives que l'on utilise couramment, et qui à l'origine avaient valeur positive, niée par la simple particule négative de l'époque *(ne)*: *ne **rien** manger, ne **plus** parler, ne **jamais** s'en sortir, ne **pas** marcher, ne **point** coudre*. Le même type de structure «substantif+verbe» existait dans les premiers temps de ce type d'expression, avant qu'elle ne soit grammaticalement réinterprétée par les générations successives de locuteurs.