# A few questions about the French version of the Canadian national anthem

Tags: sens

> Ô Canada!
>   Terre de nos aïeux,
>   Ton front est ceint de **fleurons** glorieux!
>   Car ton bras sait porter l'épée,
>   Il sait porter la croix!
>   Ton histoire est une épopée
>   **Des plus brillants exploits.**
>   Et ta valeur, **de foi trempée**,
>   Protégera nos foyers et nos droits.
>   Protégera nos foyers et nos droits.

There are three things that I don't understand in the lyrics. First of all, what does **fleurons** mean? I looked it up in two dictionaries, but the meanings they gave me were *jewels* and *flagships*. So, I'm not really sure how to make sense out of this with these two words substituted for **fleurons**. My second question is how exactly do you understand the phrase **de foi trempée**? And my third question is in the line **des plus brillants exploits**, why do we need to say **plus** (more)? Are we comparing the brilliant deeds to something?

Merci beaucoup d'avance pour votre aide précieuse.

Comment: Meanwhile, in another sense of the word, what I don't understand about the French lyrics is why in English "we stand on guard for thee" but in French thou standest on guard for us... :)

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't think I'm following you.

Comment: In English, we say "O Canada, we stand on guard for thee," but in French one says, "Your valour (Ô Canada) will protect our homes and our rights" — who defends whom is reversed. But I'm being tongue-in-cheek when I imply that there's any meaning to be drawn from it.

Comment: I see now. I thought that but wasn't sure. Why would you say that in King James language though?

Comment: In imitation of "we stand on guard for *thee*".

Comment: I got ya now. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[Fleurons](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fleurons/1)* means here the ornament in form of flower located on a crown, like a laurel wreath.

***De foi trempée*** is a poetical inversion. Standard French would be *trempée dans la foi*, i.e. steeped in faith.

*...épopée **des plus brillants exploits*** is more a superlative than a comparative. The deeds are not compared to anything particular. That just means something like "...an epic made of the brightest achievements".

You might also have trouble with ***ceint*** which is a very rare verb in modern French ([ceindre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ceindre)), meaning encircled. Derived words like *ceinture* (belt) are common though.

Finally, the word ***valeur*** has a meaning mostly forgotten in modern French: *ta bravoure, ton courage*, i.e. your bravery/valor (not value.)

Comment: My first idea was to write *soaked in faith* but *steeped* looks better indeed. Answer updated.

Comment: To add a note to this good answer: An English speaker may be surprised not only by the inversion in *de foi trempée* but also by *de* — note that @jlliagre defaulted to a more common wording when uninverting. It's more or less instrumental: *trempée* by using *foi*.

Answer (score 3):

You found jewels and flagships because fleurons is often used metaphorically to designate the most precious item of a collection (of jewels) or the best ship in a navy fleet.
De foi trempée could refer to the phrase "une épée à l'acier bien trempé", i.e. a strong blade: their soul was plunged into faith like red-hot steel is plunged into water to cool it.

Comment: I really like your take on "de foi trempée," which I could see leading to "Your bravery, reinforced/fortified/bolstered by [your] faith, will protect our homes and liberty."